# Dá para tratar o event do submit form com jquery de forma a mudar os valores enviados ao servidor?

Tags: jquery, html, formulário

Tenho um servidor em java que recebe um objeto com inclusive outros objetos dentro do objeto. Gostaria de saber se dá para alterar o submit de tal forma que possa mudar a estrutura permitindo colocar um objeto em json na forma:

```
{
    data1:"asdasda",
    data2:{
        data1:"dasdasd",
        data2:"asdasdasda",
        data3:"dasdasd"
    },
    data3:{
        data1:"asdasdas",
        data2:"asdasdasd",
        data3:"asdasdasd"
    }
}
```

O exemplo é meio simples. mas o objeto a ser enviado tem muitos campos que não quis explicitar pq segue este padrão. 
Mas caso não fique claro. Posso elaborar um exemplo mais claro do objeto ou da estrutura.

O problema que no servidor recebemos um objeto desta forma. e no cliente tem um form html. Queria que o form contivesse os dados mas não consegui.

Comment: É possível sim.

Comment: Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Não ficou clara sua pergunta. O objeto que está enviando também é json ou quer encaixar um json dentro do objeto que envia?